# Using springboot starter POMs for development and production

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Why do most example projects for Springboot use [starter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters) POMs without a version? The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter-poms) makes no mention of what version is being used.

For instance, using `web` starter without a version...

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
```

...I'm assuming pulls the latest snapshot based on the [POM](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-web/pom.xml)? I suppose that's convenient for development, but then again, I've never used dependencies *without* a version number, so this feels strange.

Is it safe to use starter packages for production if I configure the dependency with a specific version, such as the example below, or should starters be used for development only?

```
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples do not define any version because these are managed by a so-called *dependency management* section. Maven has [such support](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for years and we added the necessary to offer a similar experience with Gradle.

This is actually a very sane practice: if you have a project with several modules, you should rationalize the versions that you are using in one central place; you should also make sure your project uses a consistent version of a dependency or a set of dependencies.

This is also described [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html)

I would recommend you to use this practice across the board: writing down the version in each module means that you have to update that at multiple places when you need to upgrade. Of course, you should scope that properly: unrelated projects shouldn't share the same dependency management section as you may want to upgrade libraries version independently.

Comment: To be clear, [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html) say to specify version for the parent pom, but not on starters, since starters derive their version from the parent, correct?

Comment: There is only one version :) What a spring-boot-starter-web 1.3.4 would mean if there is not Spring Boot 1.3.4 anyway?